# Matching case words in strings python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a function that check if a word is in string OR the word has `len(word)-1` chars in common with each word in the string.

For example:

```
word: match   string: There is a match   -> True
word: matck   string: There is a match   -> True
```

The output need to be True for both examples because `matck-1=matc` and `match-1=matc`

I have wrote the below code so far:

```
for idx, f in enumerate(files):
    for word in words:
        if term in f:
            numOfWord[idx] += 1
        else:
            file_words = f.split()
            for f_word in file_words:
                if word[:-1] == file_word[:-1]:
                    numOfWords[idx] += 1
```

But it's not good because I have a very big list of word and very big dir of long files so the run time is not realistic.

Comment: Wait, so you essentially only care about the first `n-1` characters for a word of length `n`? `match` and `latch` would not match because the off-by-one isn’t at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Levenshtein distance to check that

```
def minimumEditDistance(s1,s2):
if len(s1) > len(s2):
    s1,s2 = s2,s1
distances = range(len(s1) + 1)
for index2,char2 in enumerate(s2):
    newDistances = [index2+1]
    for index1,char1 in enumerate(s1):
        if char1 == char2:
            newDistances.append(distances[index1])
        else:
            newDistances.append(1 + min((distances[index1],
                                         distances[index1+1],
                                         newDistances[-1])))
    distances = newDistances
return distances[-1]


print(minimumEditDistance("kitten","sitting"))
print(minimumEditDistance("rosettacode","raisethysword"))
```

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Python

Comment: Are you sure that the performance of your code will be better than the code in the question?

Comment: This is only an example of the algorithm, he can implement it as he likes..
You can also speed up the algorithm by using VP-trees http://www.logarithmic.net/pfh/blog/01164790008
and get it at O(nlogn)